# Rearrange ansible output

Tags: python, json, ansible, jinja2

I am debugging a var

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ result }}"
```

and getting following output.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "City": "LosAngeles"
        }, 
        {
            "Sate": "California"
        }, 
        {
            "region": "west-coast"
        }
     ]
}
```

I want to get rid of all brackets from the above output and want output something like this.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
            "City": "LosAngeles"
            "Sate": "California"
            "region": "west-coast"
     ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is the purpose you want to get rid of the bracket then

Comment: The output is really huge sometimes bcz of extra brackets in tower and cuts off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use Jinja2 formatting and split the lines. For example

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"
      vars:
        msg: |
          {% for item in result %}
          {% for k,v in item.items() %}
          {{ k }}: {{ v }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```
    "msg": [
        "City: LosAngeles", 
        "Sate: California", 
        "region: west-coast", 
        ""
    ]
```

---

Similar output can be achieved with the filter *to_yaml*. A simpler task

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"
      vars:
        msg: "{{ result|to_yaml }}"
```

gives

```
    "msg": [
        "- {City: LosAngeles}", 
        "- {Sate: California}", 
        "- {region: west-coast}", 
        ""
    ]
```